# Current best supported connector from R calling Hive?

Tags: r, hive, rjdbc

Is anyone currently using Rhive or some other way to make simple hive HQL calls from R, possibly with RJDBC or another connector?  Specifically, I have an R script on a client and a hive server on a cluster with CDH4.  The Rhive project seemed popular in 2012, but as of 2014 it has been removed from cran for lack of maintainers, which is usually a bad sign. Do you use something that works well and has an active community?